# You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs

Tags: django

[the explorer in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhu8u.png) Getting the error: You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs.

meetups/urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('meetups/', views.index)  #domain_name.com/meetups/ 
    ]
```

urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('meetups.urls'))
    ]
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

    # Create your views here.

    def index(request):
        return render(request,'templates/meetups/index.html')
```

Comment: It seems that is a problem with something you didn't provide. Have you shared whole `urls.py` files? Do you have any settings that are not in default Django project?

Comment: no, the file is complete. Actually, I'm pretty new so following a tutorial: https://youtu.be/t7DrJqcUviA
around 25 mins in

Comment: What value has your `ROOT_URLCONF` variable in settings.py? And in what folder you have settings.py and main urls.py files?

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'
both settings.py and main urls.py are in testproject folder. I have added the image in the question for reference.

Comment: That should work. Maybe share whole settings.py file, because so far everything looks ok.
If that does not help, I'll suggest start the course over without changing anything for now.

Comment: It won't let me share that much code but the only change I made is to add meetups in installed_apps list. Should I have added meetups in the templates list because that seems to have raised another problem?

Comment: I have made no new changes but now I'm getting this.

Using the URLconf defined in testproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
meetups/ [name='index']
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

Comment: Ok, then it works not, congratulations! Just go to 'localhost:8000/meetups/`, and it will be seen. You have no view for empty path so far, so it cannot show anything.

Comment: but I do have a view..it is supposed to display the index HTML file and it's not doing that.

Comment: Then change `path('meetups/', views.index)` to `path('/', views.index)`. The guy in video is explaining how paths work. Watch again that part :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `meetups/templates/index.html` to `meetups/index.html` also add `name` in your `urlpatterns`

Comment: still not working

Comment: "you have not configured any URLs" means it does not see anything as urls, it does not matter if they would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't add your app (`meetups`) into `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, which can be found in `your_project_name/settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file "*urls.py*" in "*meetups*" directory. Mine was named "*url.py*" from the installation.